# Computing Next Due Date Based on the Current Date - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A question was just asked about calculating a due-date based on the date a payment was made and the payment schedule appropriate for that payment, ie: weekly, monthly, etc...
I believe the question was deleted because of pressure to ask a better question.

If the individual returns, I want them to see the below as a possible solution. @Ba Troo this is for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original question is a little vague, but the solution I've come up with allows an individual to define their own terms as is appropriate to their specific case.

I've attached a spreadsheet: [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ak6r9nlUd1ZOjPEugW1gNw9_T1Sehw)

The formula I'm using to make the "magic" happen is in `D2`:`=B2+INDEX($G$2:$G$8,MATCH(C2,$F$2:$F$8,0))`

[image]

Comment: Typically (IMOHE), weekly would be a payment made on a specific weekday with the starting week prorated. Same with quarterly with the addition that quarterly may be by year/4 or fiscal year/4 and doesn't necessarily mean 92 days.

Comment: Agreed. I just quickly did some dirty math to demonstrate the principal. From there, if he/she gets what they need, they can tweak and bastardize the thing however they want. Just wanted to show what they could use as a starting point, really.

Comment: Please take more care with the language in your comments "tweak and edit" would be ample...

Comment: While I appreciate the sentiment, the word I picked was very much what I was trying to say. "Tweak" would already imply editing, "bastardize" has a totally different connotation. Because it seems this original problem was put forward by someone with very little Excel experience (even less than me), as with anyone learning any language/program, there is a process of cobbling together all sorts of things to make "it" work. The language I used is entirely appropriate for what I was trying to convey.

Comment: From Merriam Webster [link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bastardize): 3 : to modify especially by introducing discordant or disparate elements